# Do I need to close or destroy streams when using stream.pipeline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

When using [`stream.pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback), do I need to "close" or "destroy" any of these streams?

The documentation shows this simple example:

```js
pipeline(
  fs.createReadStream('archive.tar'),
  zlib.createGzip(),
  fs.createWriteStream('archive.tar.gz'),
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
    }
  }
);
```

but then follows by saying:

> `stream.pipeline()` leaves dangling event listeners on the streams after the callback has been invoked. In the case of reuse of streams after failure, this can cause event listener leaks and swallowed errors.

Comment: I dislike the `pipeline()` function because it really only does what it is suppose to when there are no errors.  My understand from the doc is that it will clean up the streams if there are no errors and the streams are set to autoClose (which is usually a stream default), but it will not clean them up if there are errors which I think means you end up having to listen for errors on every single stream so you can properly clean up.  It seems half implemented to me.

Comment: Thanks, @jfriend00! So I'd need to attach `.on('error', function(){ this.destroy(); })` to each?

Comment: Yes, and make sure (perhaps by code inspection of the `destroy()` method that it's going to remove all the listeners that the doc mentions.  Actually, just realized there's more to it than that.  Upon one error, you have to clean up not only that stream, but the others too, in particular, the downstream ones that haven't finished yet.